# Change the yaxis values from float to text in bar chart matlab

Tags: matlab

I already implemented the code to draw the bar chart with colors but I need to change the values on yaxis to be only 3 values(very bad which is less than 25% , bad which is between 25% and 50% , and good which more than 50%). Any help??

```
x = [0.1 0.5 1 2 3];
y = [2.0407   10.2108   19.8171   36.6688   52.2866];
xplot = 1:numel(x); 

fHand = figure;
aHand = axes('parent', fHand);
hold(aHand, 'on')

for i=xplot
    if x(i) < 0.25
        bar(i, y(i), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', 'red')
    elseif x(i) <= 0.5
        bar(i, y(i), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', 'yellow')
    elseif x(i) > 0.5
        bar(i, y(i), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', 'green')
    end
end

set(gca,'XTick', xplot); 
set(gca,'XTickLabel', x);

ylabel('Accuracy');
xlabel('level');

ylim([0 100]);
```

Original:

[image]

My Target:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will do it:

```
set(gca,'yTick',[25 50 100])
set(gca,'yTickLabel',{'Very bad','Bad','Good'})
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: but I need these values to be shown as (VB B and G)

Comment: I don't think I'm following you. What do you mean by "they need to be shown as (VB B and G)"? Is a coloured legend with these codes (VB B and G) indicating the condition?

Comment: I updated my question so you can understand what I mean. Many Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I if you can see my target in the question, I need all green values to be the same. can you do that?

Comment: You mean you want to set the y values of x=[1 2 3] to 75?